# (Name-)referencing to current chapter

Tags: cross-referencing, nameref

As I understood, I define my chapter title as follows:

```
\chapter[title in table of contents][title in header line]{title in body}
```

afterwards I add a label e.g.

```
\label{Chapter1}
```

I know that I can use something like `\nameref(Chapter1)` to display the title of the respective chapter. However, how can I display the name/title of the *current* chapter ... so the chapter in which I give the command (e.g. if I want to display the name of the current chapter in my custom footer) Please no `fancyhdr` solutions. Thanks!

Comment: 'Please no `fancyhdr` solutions' ... well.. please add a compilable document as well. Apparently, you're using `memoir`. And `\nameref(Chapter1)` will make (pdf)LaTeX turn back on you ;-) Numbered label names are also very error prone

Comment: Shall this have a link to the chapter title as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A version without any links (Will edit this later on)

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\makeatletter

\gdef\@currentchaptername{}%
\xpatchcmd{\@makechapterhead}{%
  \chapterheadstart%
}{%
  \gdef\@currentchaptername{#1}%
  \chapterheadstart%
}{\typeout{Patch success for @makechapterhead}}{\typeout{Patch failure for @makechapterhead}}


\newcommand{\currentchapref}{%
  \@currentchaptername%
}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\chapter[title in table of contents][title in header line]{title in body}\label{Chapter1}

\section{ A foo section}

This is \currentchapref. 
\chapter[title in table of contents again][title in header line again]{title in body again}\label{Chapter2}
\end{document}
```

And here is version with linking (if necessary) or use the starred macro version `\currentchapref*` to suppress links:

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\makeatletter

\gdef\@currentchaptername{}%
\xpatchcmd{\@makechapterhead}{%
  \chapterheadstart%
}{%
  \@ifundefined{@currentHref}{%
    \gdef\@currentchaptername{{}{#1}}%
  }{%
    % Store the current anchor for the chapter
    \edef\@currentchaptername{{\@currentHref}{#1}}%
  }%
  \chapterheadstart%
}{\typeout{Patch success for @makechapterhead}}{\typeout{Patch failure for @makechapterhead}}


\NewDocumentCommand{\currentchapref}{sm}{%
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}{%
    \expandafter\@secondoftwo\@currentchaptername% Use only the second argument
  }{%
    \expandafter\hyperlink\@currentchaptername%
  }%
}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\chapter[title in table of contents][title in header line]{title in body}\label{Chapter1}

\section{ A foo section}

\blindtext[10]
This is \currentchapref. 
\chapter[title in table of contents again][title in header line again]{title in body again}\label{Chapter2}
\end{document}
```